# TouchEvent with 3 fingers - custom TouchEvent?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, multi-touch

I'm looking for to detect touchEvent made with 3 fingers. (no more, no less)
I would like to create custom event...
I don't know how.

I would like a really simple listener to add (for sharing) like

```
stage.addEventListener( TouchEvent.THREE_TOUCH_BEGIN, MyFunction);
...
```

I don't want to use eventDispatcher (ugly stuff and not intuitive way)

I don't understand how to, if I need to code a custom event or TouchEvent... or include custom event in my class... I'm lost.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Comment to your thread here https://forums.adobe.com/thread/1689748:

you must be really not realizing the fact that event is just an object that contains a peace of data. Your constructor code doesn't make any sense. How `nTouch` could be possibly more then 3? Are you trying to put some recognition logic into event? You should place recognition logic (something that listens to TouchEvent.TOUCH_BEGIN and TouchEvent.TOUCH_END, and keeps track of touch ids and everything) in one place and when you see "a-ha, we have three touches at the same time" – create and dispatch your custom event.

Comment: i think i'm an idiot (or just a designer mind) because i do not undestand what your are writing. i suppose it's the same pb to understand a gesture delagation. ;) in my tests i'm using TOUCH_BEGIN and TOUCH_END to determine how many touch in same time, if i've 3, i do my job to recognize the pattern, by instantiate an object with the 3 TouchPoints...

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to try [Gestouch](https://github.com/fljot/Gestouch) (multitouch gesture recognition library for Flash (ActionScript))

Using this library, you can try something like:

```
 var tripleTap:TapGesture = new TapGesture(myButton);
 tripleTap.numTapsRequired = 3;
 tripleTap.addEventListener(GestureEvent.GESTURE_RECOGNIZED, onTripleTap);

 function onTripleTap(event:GestureEvent):void
 {
     // handle triple tap!
 }
```

Comment: thank you gPeart.
i know Gestouch, it's too big for my needs.
- only need a Touch with 3 fingers (no gestures,etc, etc)<br>
- not triple tap... ;) but i suppose it'was an example.  I remember that you can give the number of touch for gesture..
- i want to share the class on github, and perhaps it will be a prob to share this lib to...

Comment: > i'm working on a class for detect wooden smart pieces with touchpad, with 3 touchPad.
> (https://github.com/mrbbp/wooden-smart-toy) and would like to simplifie use.
> therfore i want to customize TouchEvent for that particular case.

Comment: You could really easily write custom gesture recognizer for Gestouch for that, but if this is the only thing you need – probably, you're right, the whole lib might be too much for you.

What's the problem anyway? Create custom event, dispatch it when needed. What is the issue exactly?

Comment: @Pavelfljōt, exactly, I have done several custom gesture recognizer and works very fine. You did an awesome job! :)

Comment: @gPeart thank you) care to share them, if they might be useful for public? e-mail

Comment: @Pavelfljōt: in fact i was loving the idea to have a simple listener. i don't like the eventdispatcher syntax. i find it ugly and not so simple to understand. If it's not at my level i stop... i have other things in mind. the lib work as is... it will be enough at this time. And with your lib i stop a dev some years ago because i was unable to delegate gesture, to combine a long press and swipe gesture (i've understood concept but can't write it). I'm just a designer, not a dev and this is certainly my limit.

Comment: @Pavelfljōt for sure :)